# Custom form register

Tags: forms

i have any fields form register user drupal 7. I want to when user choice select box : User 1 or User then any fields hide or show. Please help me
Thank to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields):

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition. When editing a node (or any other entity type that
>   supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are
>   dynamically modified with the States API. You can, for example, define
>   a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser"
>   checkbox is checked.

**EDIT**

To learn how to use the Field UI and create these form items for Users please see:

- https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui
- https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/options

Comment: Thank tenken
so can i creat checkbox where ? 
sorry for my English

Comment: @ChúaLười please see my edit.

Comment: great! i have done it with Conditional Fields 
Thank you so much :D @tenken